# Fetching posts that match a User Profile setting

Tags: users, profiles, dropdown

I have a Custom Field in my User Profile page that allows site authors to specify which town they come from when they set up their account. The towns are in the form of a selectable dropdown select element.

What I would like to do is query the WP database to populate a dropdown of all the towns on the **front end** of my WP site and, when one town is selected, go to a page that lists all the authors who live in the town selected.

I don't have any code as I'm not even sure how to begin such a thing.

Comment: It will be difficult to say without knowing how you are saving custom field in profile...

Comment: Well, _"I don't have any code"_ is a bit of a tough one. Sketching out concepts doesn't work too well and the answer anyway would need to be a fully fledged plugin. In short: Please [edit] your question. So far it's _too broad_. Research [tag:redirect] and [tag:ajax].